# Python + Selenium: fill text input in the modal form

Tags: python, selenium

I am a new to Selenium. I click a button and this gives me a modal form. I want to fill text area on this modal.

```
<input id="name" name="name" 
    class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" 
    ng-model="model.newInstanceSpec.name" 
    ng-required="true" 
    required="required" 
    type="text">
```

I tried `find_element_by_id`, `find_element_by_class_name` etc. I didn't find anything.

The error stack:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="name"]

below is the screenshot of modal form
[image]

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you please share error trace/

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="name"]

Comment: @DogushanKAYA, give us HTML code of modal popup or URL of the page.

Comment: can you see image ?

Comment: @DogushanKAYA, please delete your answer for upload screenshot, I had esit your post and move the screenshot in your question

Comment: Did you try sleep for 15-20 seconds before find it? If the sleep work,  means  the modal form need little long time to load, then change sleep to wait API

Comment: i use WebDriverWait(driver,15)  function.

Comment: sleep works for me thank you @yong

Comment: so you need to change the wait condition, like use `element_to_be_clickable`, don't use `presence_of_element_located`

Comment: yep . i used prsence_of_element_located. thank you very much. have a good day :) @yong

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sleep for 15-20 seconds before find it

If the sleep work, means the modal form need little long time to load, then change sleep API to wait API.

If you already use wait API, please change the wait condition. like change from `presence_of_element_located` to `element_to_be_clickable`